# When adding a gpg key with homedir parameter error

Tags: gnupg, pgp, public-key-encryption

When adding a key using the cmd

```
Gpg2 –-homedir . –-gen-key
```

And Im getting the error

> Can’t connect to the agent: Invalid value passed to IPC

This is something to do with the homedir parameter but I need it there as my keyring exists in that dir.

Answer (score 3):

After finding [several](http://lists.wald.intevation.org/pipermail/gpg4win-users-en/2010-March/000454.html) [mailing list](https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2013-April/046408.html) [threads](https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2012-April/044164.html) with no answer to this question, I finally got it working.

First: use absolute paths for the homedir. E.g. instead of `--homedir=.` use `--homedir="$(pwd)"`

If that alone doesn't fix it, manually launch gpg-agent passing the same homedir (kill any existing agents first)

```
gpg-agent --homedir="$(pwd)" --daemon
```

Comment: Manually starting `gpg-agent` like this answer describes illustrated the problem for me which was that the absolute path of the homedir was too long. The `gpg-agent` aborted with `gpg-agent[3857]: socket name '/some/long/path` is too long`. Changing to a shorter path fixed it and did not require manually restarting the agent.

Answer (score 0):

Look in ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf and ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf for a line with GPGHOME=

If you are looking to statically  change the location of  GPGHOME run as such:
GPGHOME=$path_to_'.' // i.e. ~/gpgtweaks/ << being the . in your question

gpg2 --full-gen-key

In the event that you still fail to get an agent launch run:

gpg-connect-agent

that should force a agent restart also of  use is ADDING `use-agent`  in your ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf